# Игра найди кота

Tags: android

Решила попробовать написать простенькую игру типа найди кота или найди собачку) И Хотела бы узнать как вообще пишутся такого рода игры.

Игра примерно будет такая: Есть 4 животных и нужно допустим найти котенка. Игрок нажимает  на котенка и ему выдается сообщение что это правильный выбор, а если игрок нажал на то животное, то сообщение о том, что неправильный выбор.

На мой взгляд я бы делала так: Создала бы в БД таблицу или json файл с полями (животное1, животное2, животное3, животное4, вопрос, ответ)... т.е. в колонках животное1-животное4 будут идти различные вариации животных, ну вопрос понятно, а в колонке ответ название правильного животного. случайным образом выбирать какую-то запись из БД и выводить вопрос и животных в ImageView и проверять каким-то образом..

НО хотелось бы узнать как вообще такого рода игры создаются? Можете всю логику описать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Логика игры-викторины очень [подробно описана](https://books.google.ru/books?id=8E_ADAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&hl=ru&pg=PA165#v=onepage&q&f=false) в книге П.Дейтела "Android для разработчиков" (создание игры Flag Quiz, по ссылке отрывки из книги, но ее не сложно найти и скачать целиком) - вместо кнопок из примера вы можете использовать картинки с животными.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду читать.